# log4j cannot write log in kafka consumer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, log4j, appender

I need to write logs in a kafka consummer but i obtain this error :

```
2020-03-22 22:22:20 DEBUG [Producer clientId=producer-1] Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.

2020-03-22 22:22:20 DEBUG [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initialize connection to node localhost:9092 

(id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request

2020-03-22 22:22:20 DEBUG [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 

(id: -1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1
```

**log4j.properties** :

```
log4j.logger.logGen=TRACE, Kafka

log4j.appender.Kafka=org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.Kafka.topic=kafka
log4j.appender.Kafka.brokerList=localhost:9092
log4j.appender.Kafka.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Kafka.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
```

**KafkaClass.scala**

```
import org.apache.log4j._

object KafkaClass extends App {

  val logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  logger.info("kafka info")
  logger.error("kafka error")
  logger.warn("kafka warn")

}
```

I don't see what is the problem, thank you for you help

Update : 
I have this message console :

```
2020-03-24 14:27:17 DEBUG [Producer clientId=producer-1] Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
2020-03-24 14:27:17 DEBUG [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initialize connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
2020-03-24 14:27:17 DEBUG [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1
2020-03-24 14:27:17 DEBUG Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
2020-03-24 14:27:17 DEBUG Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
2020-03-24 14:27:17 DEBUG Added sensor with name node--1.latency
2020-03-24 14:27:17 DEBUG [Producer clientId=producer-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
```

but still don't receive message in the consumer

Comment: Based on the error, Kafka isn't running on localhost 9092

Comment: no, Kafka is running on localhost 9002, I verify that

Comment: Yeah? Can you show your Activity/Task monitor output for it? And your server.properties?

Comment: I fix this issue but i still not having the message in the consumer (i cannot copy the console message , it is too long for a comment)

Comment: I edit the post @cricket_007

Comment: Are you sure Kafka is running? Show its logs. Run `nc -vz localhost 9092`. Use `kafka-console-consumer`... This isn't a Scala issue